# Why do my plants sprout and die in my aquaponic system?

Tags: aquaponics, plants

I have an aquaponic system.  My herbs sprout and grow to about 3 inches, then wilt and fall over.  Is there something lacking, or is this a result of root rot?  Should I lower the water level?  I have them growing under a 50 watt grow light, could the amount of light be a problem as well?

Comment: This appears to be a pure [gardening](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/) question

Comment: My first thought would be root rot.  However without pictures of your setup, it is hard to say. Can you supply images?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to sustainability (more info in [this meta post on the boundaries between Gardening SE and this site](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3/where-do-we-draw-the-line-between-sustainable-living-and-gardening))

Comment: @THelper why wasn't the question migrated?

Comment: @J.Musser Not sure. I think I asked the Gardening mods if they wanted it and then forgot about this question.